# Why does Outputcache expire too early?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a ASP.NET Webforms Application. For better performance i set the Outputcache in the Page-Load of the Masterpage programmatically:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // [...] do stuff [...]

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Server);
            Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);  // ignore Cache-Control Header from Request
            Response.Cache.SetSlidingExpiration(false);
            Response.Cache.VaryByParams["*"] = true;
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(somedateinthefuture); // plus 5 Days from now
            Response.AddFileDependency(pathtoafile);        // a file which will be overwritten when cache should be fully cleared (this works)
        }
}
```

So for every unique Url the HTML is cached. This works quite fine.

Problem:

- Many Entries get removed randomly after 1 or 3 Minutes from Cache although it should last for many Days
- Some entries stay for 24 Hours and more but also get removed prior to duration

What i checked:

- The Dependency-File has not been updated
- The IIS-Application or Application-Pool has not been restarted or recycled
- Memory of Pool is not at maximum
- On Test-Website Outputcache stays much longer then in Production-Website
- Single Items do expire, not the whole cache
- Pressing "STRG+F5" reloads the called site
- IIS 7.5, ASP.NET 4.6.1

What can cause the removal of single cache-items. Maybe Bots? But shouldn't this be prevented by SetValidUntilExpires(true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason has been a setting in the IIS7-Application. The Application Pool did recycle itself or removed single Cache-Entries when it reached a size of more than 400 Megabyte.